# Как работает std::initializer_list c++

Tags: c++

Стало очень интересно как работает `std:: initializer_list`. Каким образом достигается то, что мы можем передать любое количество аргументов в его конструктор. Я посмотрел его реализацию, но в конструкторе всего лишь 2 параметра, а передать туда мы можем гораздо больше. Как тогда это работает, каким образом я могу сделать так-же?

Comment: typename... Types

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, спасибо, но что насчёт стандартной реализации initializer_list, там это реализовано без вариативных шаблонов

Comment: Я только 2 способа знаю. А этой странной фичёй сдд не пользуюсь(напрямую).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это волшебный класс.

Невозможно сделать другой такой же. Знание о том, как он работает, встроено в компилятор.

Как убедиться? Можно вот так:

```
auto x = {1, 2, 3};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), std::initializer_list<int>>);
```